# Как сохранить состояние интерпретатора python?

Tags: python

Как сохранить состояние интерпретатора и отправить на другую машину где его можно будет восстановить?

Comment: Что именно вы имеете ввиду под состоянием интерпретатора?

Comment: Всё что можно. Надо для отладки, если упало с непонятным exception. Порой не хватает информации о переменных.

Comment: Сунуть его в виртуалку. В нужный момент виртуалку уснуть и переправить на другую машину. Там разбудить. :) С другой стороны - оно уже ж упало, какие там переменные...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14672624/memory-dump-using-python

Comment: @Akina, есть такой язык программирования Euphoria. При падении программы текст ошибки и стектрейс записываются в файл, туда же записывается состояние (частичное) локальных и глобальных переменных. Правда с типами данных там не очень богато - есть только числа ("атомы") и эквивалент питоновских списков (строки - это набор чисел в списке). Этакий процедурный Лисп. Вот для отладки такой дамп мог бы быть удобен, правда в Python не всегда по repr можно понять в каком состоянии находится объект.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно сообразить что-то вроде

```
import sys

def dump_state(t, v, tb):
    if hasattr(sys, 'ps1') or not sys.stderr.isatty():
        sys.__excepthook__(t, v, tb)
    else:
        import traceback
        from pprint import pprint

        traceback.print_exception(t, v, tb)

        with open('state.txt', 'w') as fh:
            while tb:
                pprint({
                    'globals': tb.tb_frame.f_globals,
                    'locals': tb.tb_frame.f_locals
                }, stream=fh)
                tb = tb.tb_next

sys.excepthook = dump_state
```

После вылета необработанного исключения в state.txt будут все глобальные и локальные переменные для анализа состояния.

Comment: А если locals запихнуть в pickle и развернуть на другой машине?

Comment: @eri да вариантов-то масса, что можно в обработчик `dump_state` запихнуть. Как в плане форматов сохранения данных, так и в плане того, что именно сохранять и как потом использовать.